# How to safely store and access user session data

Tags: javascript, php, security, architecture

I am currently learning about security aspects in web applications.

My application used to identify the current user by a cookie which was created on successful login. It contained the user's id. Every time the user has made a request to the database, my application would use that id to select only those results that were associated with this id.

However, as I learned, it would be no problem at all to simply change that cookie's value and therefore get access to another user's data.

My issue now is: how would I safely store such data and make it available to both PHP and Javascript?

I thought of HTML5 sessionStorage, but that would be vulnerable too.

My second thought was to store it by PHP only in a $_SESSION variable, but then I could not access its value via Javascript.

I feel like I can not wrap my head around the basic concepts of how to create a secure and functional user-management system.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you can open a session at the server that verify the cookie with the associate user id

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you do not need this value client-side (javascript)? Any kind of validation like that should be done server side.

Comment: Have you read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php ?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the user id data only in the session. Why do you need cookies?
To communicate between JS and PHP use ajax. Best library for this is [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) 
.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

1. Add a userKey field to the database.
2. When user logs in, generate a random unique string and save it in DB
3. Save this string in cookie. Save user ID in cookie.

On the next visit, select from the database user with the corresponding userKey and ID.

It is somewhat secure, because the string is random, so only bruteforce helps.

Longer the string - harder to bruteforce.

The solution is simple, it can be upgraded by using crypting of ID, checking IP, etc.